# Solr spellcheck polish characters

Tags: solr

I would be more than grateful for information if sb was able to configure spellcheck in SOLR, so queries returns values when polish characters were replaced with unicoded?

I have spellcheck enabled however I am not getting any results when searching 'slub', while I am getting plenty for 'ślub'

Cheers

Comment: Hi, welcome in SO. In order to get help,  your questions need to be as detailed as possible. Please add: relevant code in your schema.xml, query used, results returned and results expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) in you spellchecking field configuration.

```
<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false"/>
```

> Converts alphabetic, numeric, and symbolic Unicode characters which are not in the first 127 ASCII characters (the "Basic Latin" Unicode block) into their ASCII equivalents, if one exists.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment. However I believe that ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory works oposite way.
I believe that would transfer 'ślub' to 'slub' instead 'slub' to 'ślub'

Comment: It works both way. Use it for indexing and searching, so that in every cases you end up with "slub".
Searching "slub" or "ślub" would find the same set of documents.

Comment: Thanks a ton again. Unfortunately that does not solve the case, as I do not want to change the form of indexed word, as it may change its meaning. Slub is not the best example, but 'mól' and 'mol' is.